# tf.nn.in_top_k(logits,y,1) out of range error but equal actually

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm doing my first Neural Network with a binary classification, but I got an error when I try to evaluate the model with:

```py
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits,y,1)
```

where

- logits tensor is : **predictions** : shape [batch_size = 52, num_classes = 1], type **float32**
- y tensor is      : **targets**: shape [batch_size=52], type int32

I got this error :

```py
targets[1] is out of range
     [[{{node in_top_k/InTopKV2}}]]
```

---

After some debugging time , I understood that the values of my tensor y must be <= to num_classes, so the first value of the tensor y equal to  1 is considered as out of range, even tough the parameter num_classes = 1.

How can I allow my tensor values to be equal to num_classes and only strictly inferior ? Or is there another way ?

In my opinion, num_classes should equal 1 because it's a binary classification so 1 neuron output is needed.

---

**EDIT**
Here's my **full code** :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
n_inputs = 28 
n_hidden1 = 15
n_hidden2 = 5
n_outputs = 1
reset_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X") 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None), name="y")   #None => any
def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.shape[1])
        stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(n_inputs) 
        init = tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddev) #matrice n_inputs x n_neurons values proche de 0    
        W = tf.Variable(init,name="kernel")  #weights random
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name="bias")
        Z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
        tf.cast(Z,tf.int32)
        if activation is not None:
            return activation(Z)
        else:
            return Z
def to_one_hot(y):
    n_classes = y.max() + 1
    m = len(y)
    Y_one_hot = np.zeros((m, n_classes))
    Y_one_hot[np.arange(m), y] = 1
    return Y_one_hot
hidden1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1",
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
hidden2 = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2",
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
logits = neuron_layer(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")
xentropy = tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(tf.to_float(y),logits) 
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
learning_rate = 0.01
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits,y,1)
labels_max = tf.reduce_max(y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
n_epochs = 40
batch_size = 50
def shuffle_batch(X, y, batch_size):  #Homogeneisation et decoupage en paquets(n_batches)
    rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
    n_batches = len(X) // batch_size
    for batch_idx in np.array_split(rnd_idx, n_batches):
        X_batch, y_batch = X[batch_idx], y[batch_idx]
        yield X_batch, y_batch


with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    X_temp,Y_temp = X_batch,y_batch
    feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch}
    print("feed",feed_dict)
    print("\n y_batch :",y_batch,y_batch.dtype)
    print("\n X_batch :",X_batch,X_batch.dtype,X_batch.shape)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for X_batch, y_batch in shuffle_batch(X_train, Y_train, batch_size):
            y_batch=y_batch.astype(np.int32)
            X_batch=X_batch.astype(np.float32)
            sess.run(training_op,feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        #acc_batch = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        #acc_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_valid, y: y_valid})
        #print(epoch, "Batch accuracy:", acc_batch, "Val accuracy:", acc_val)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")
    #some tests
    print("y eval :",y.eval(feed_dict={X:X_temp,y:Y_temp}).shape)

    y_one_hot=to_one_hot(y.eval(feed_dict={X:X_temp,y:Y_temp}))
    print("y_one_hot :",y_one_hot.shape)

    print("logits eval : ",logits.eval(feed_dict={X:X_temp,y:Y_temp}))
    #print(correct.eval(feed_dict={X:X_temp,y:Y_temp}))
    print(labels_max.eval(feed_dict={X:X_temp,y:Y_temp}))
```

Comment: Can you print out your target labels ? Just print the output of `tf.reduce_max(labels)`

Comment: `print( tf.reduce_max(y).eval(feed_dict={X:X_temp,y:Y_temp})) `   gave me 1

Comment: Are you using one hot encoded logits ? If yes then what's your max label value?

Comment: how do you one hot encode logits , I try this :                                                        `def to_one_hot(y):
    n_classes = y.max() + 1
    m = len(y)
    Y_one_hot = np.zeros((m, n_classes))
    Y_one_hot[np.arange(m), y] = 1
    return Y_one_hot`                                                                                                but  logits dtype is float ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/in_top_k), `tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions, targets, k)` has arguments:

- `predictions`: A Tensor of type float32. A `batch_size x classes` tensor.
- `targets`: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64. A `batch_size` vector of class ids.
- `k`: An int. Number of top elements to look at for computing precision.

As you are performing binary classification, i.e., has two classes, so the shape of `logits` tensor in your case should be `(52, 2)` while the shape of `y` should be `(52,)`. Here, `logits` is basically `one-hot encoded` tensor. This is the reason why your are getting above error.

Consider the below example:

**Example 1**:

```
res = tf.nn.in_top_k([[0,1], [1,0], [0,1], [1, 0], [0, 1]], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 1)
```

Here, shape of `logits` is (5, 2) while `y` is (5,). If you will do `tf.reduce_max(y)`, you will get `1`, which is less than number of classes and hence okay.

This will work fine and output `[False False  True False  True]`

**Example 2**:

```
res = tf.nn.in_top_k([[0,1], [1,0], [0,1], [1, 0], [0, 1]], [0, 2, 1, 1, 1], 1)
```

If you will do `tf.reduce_max(y)`, you will get `2`,  which is equal to the number of classes.
This will raises an error: `InvalidArgumentError: targets[1] is out of range`

**EDIT**: In your above code, make following modifications:

- change `n_outputs = 1` to `n_outputs = 2`
- change `sess.run(training_op,feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})` to `_, cost, acc = sess.run([training_op, loss, accuracy], feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: to_one_hot(y_batch)})`
- change `correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)` to `correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, tf.argmax(y, 1), 1)`

**Code**(random data used):

```
n_inputs = 28 
n_hidden1 = 15
n_hidden2 = 5
n_outputs = 2

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X") 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, 2), name="y")   #None => any

def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.shape[1])
        stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(n_inputs) 
        init = tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddev) #matrice n_inputs x n_neurons values proche de 0    
        W = tf.Variable(init,name="kernel")  #weights random
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name="bias")
        Z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
        tf.cast(Z,tf.int32)
        if activation is not None:
            return activation(Z)
        else:
            return Z

def to_one_hot(y):
    n_classes = y.max() + 1
    m = len(y)
    Y_one_hot = np.zeros((m, n_classes))
    Y_one_hot[np.arange(m), y] = 1
    return Y_one_hot

hidden1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1",
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
hidden2 = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2",
                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
logits = neuron_layer(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")
xentropy = tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(tf.to_float(y),logits) 
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
learning_rate = 0.01
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits,tf.argmax(y, 1),1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
n_epochs = 1

X_train = np.random.rand(100, 28)
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32)

Y_train = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 2, size = 100, dtype=np.int32) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        _, cost, corr, acc = sess.run([training_op, loss, correct, accuracy], feed_dict={X: X_train, y: to_one_hot(Y_train)})
        print(corr)
        print('Loss: {} Accuracy: {}'.format(cost, acc))
```

Comment: logits is a float , so try to one hot encode it , is going to give me a tensor shape of (52,51) due to the continuous nature of floating point values, it's not advisable .!  Thanks for your answer , I understood how it works but don't know how to one hot encode logits to have its shape equal to (52,2) ... Am I wrong?

Comment: purpose is to give you a fair idea what to do in your case. I used a random X data of shape `(100, 28)` and Y data of shape `(100,)`

Comment: Can you explain me this line ?                                                                                       `                                                                 
 _, cost, corr, acc = sess.run([training_op, loss, correct, accuracy], feed_dict={X: X_train, y: to_one_hot(Y_train)})
 `    thanks for your precious help and time !

Comment: Yeah, sure. Here, we are basically running all the operations leading to `loss`, `training_op`, `correct` and `accuracy`, and return their result (with x = X_train and y = one-hot encoded Y_train as inputs)  and finally storing them in variables.